# MVC Ajax form with a file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

iam just using an AJAX Form to submit a Textbox with a data and File in MVC5.
here is Ajax form

```
 <script>
function BeginRequest() {
    alert('begining');
}
function submitform() {

    var fileinput = $('#file2')[0].files;
    if (fileinput.length <= 0)
        alert("no file to upload");
    var fromdata = new FormData();
    fromdata.append('a', fileinput[0]);
    debugger;
    $('#Form2').submit();


}
function OnFail() {
    alert('faiil');
}

 </script>

  <div id="divresponse">

   </div>

   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitFiles", "Home", null,
       new AjaxOptions()
       {
           UpdateTargetId = "divresponse",
           InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           OnBegin = "BeginRequest",
           OnFailure = "OnFail()"
       }, new { id = "Form2", enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"        }))
{
 <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" />

<input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" value="aaa" />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="submitform()" />

}
```

> i  have used already  used

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

in layout .cshtml and have config changes

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /
```

> Yet Request.FIles in SubmitFiles actionmethod its count is zero.

here is image[image]

> In jquery i can get files  and in fiddler [image]
>
> don't know why files count is zero in action method and why my BeginRequest and onfail methods are firing in any scenario after form is submited. I am submitting using $('#form2").submit()

Comment: You cannot use `Ajax.BeginForm()` to upload files. You need to use `FormData` with a specifi set of ajax options which `Ajax.BeginForm()` does not set. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for how to do it.